# valid PDF signature without using hardware HSM or usb Token

Tags: certificates, digital-signature, physical, hsm

I have a DMS system(alfresco) that needs to sign approx 50.000 valid signatures a year.
The signing certificate needs to be acquired from one of the affiliated sub-CA's.
So according to the Adobe CDS certificate policy, are they obligating me to use a hardware HSM or usb Token? I want to use SoftHSM instead. It is free & opensource (but no hardware).

Is this possible?

Comment: How did you resolve this problem ? I'm thinking buying a Digital Certificate for HSM and trying to install in SoftHSM.. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CDS Certificate Policy ([available here](http://www.adobe.com/misc/pdfs/Adobe_CDS_CP.pdf)) specifies in section 6.1.1

> Subscriber key pairs must be generated in a manner that ensures that
>   the private key is not known by anybody other than the Subscriber or a
>   Subscriber’s authorized representative. Subscriber key pairs must be
>   generated in a medium that prevents exportation or duplication and
>   that meets or exceed FIPS 140-1 Level 2 certification standards.

SoftHSM is not *FIPS 140-1 Level 2* compliant. As far as I know, level 2 and upper requires a hardware cryptographic module.

Note that the [AATL program](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list2.html) (successor of CDS) has similar requirements but it provides a larger set of Certification Authority which could provide you either a physical signature certificate or a signature SaaS solution.